# Добавление DOM-элемента после завершения всех перемещений

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Есть карусель, которую время от времени пытаюсь анимировать:

```
'use strict';
let leftButton = document.body.querySelector('#toLeft');
let rightButton = document.body.querySelector('#toRight');

leftButton.addEventListener('click', leftButtonClickHandler);
rightButton.addEventListener('click', rightButtonClickHandler);


function leftButtonClickHandler() {
  let box = document.body.querySelector('.carousel');
  let items = box.querySelectorAll('img');

  box.append(items[0]);
}

function rightButtonClickHandler() {
  let box = document.body.querySelector('.carousel');
  let items = box.querySelectorAll('img');

  for (let item of items) {
      item.addEventListener('transitionend', itemTtransitionendHandler);
      item.classList.toggle('fast', false);
      item.style.left = '135px';
  }

  //box.prepend(items[items.length - 1]);
}

function itemTtransitionendHandler() {
    event.target.classList.toggle('fast', true);
    event.target.style.left = '0px';
}
```

Ссылка на песочницу: https://codepen.io/muturgan/pen/JpdjVK 
  Для компактности анимацию пока прикручиваю только к перемотке вправо. Задумка такая: сначала циферки медленно двигаются на 1 позицию вправо, потом мгновенно возвращаются на исходные позиции, потом последний элемент карусели встает на первую позицию.

Синхронное возвращение элементов на исходные позиции я, слава богу, осилил. Осталось поместить последний элемент в начало карусели. Этот код сейчас закомментирован. Его выполнение ломает карусель. Как я понимаю, опять же из-за асинхронного выполнения. Событий, на которые можно было бы повесить обработчики, уже нет.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно синхронно поместить последний элемент в начало карусели после полного возвращения ее элементов на исходные позиции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот. https://muturgan.github.io/carousel/

```
'use strict';
let leftButton = document.body.querySelector('#toLeft');
let rightButton = document.body.querySelector('#toRight');
let box = document.body.querySelector('.carousel');
let items = box.querySelectorAll('img');
let count = 0;

leftButton.addEventListener('click', leftButtonClickHandler);
rightButton.addEventListener('click', rightButtonClickHandler);


function leftButtonClickHandler() {
  box.append(items[0]);
  items = box.querySelectorAll('img');
}

function rightButtonClickHandler() {
  for (let item of items) {
      item.addEventListener('transitionend', itemTtransitionendHandler);
      item.classList.toggle('fast', false);
      item.style.left = '135px';
  }
}

function itemTtransitionendHandler() {
    count++;
    event.target.classList.toggle('fast', true);
    event.target.style.left = '0px';

    if (count % items.length === 0) {
        box.prepend(items[items.length - 1]);
        items = box.querySelectorAll('img');
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Все это конечно притянуто за уши. Пойду учить промисы.